# Help find induction question

Tags: induction

starts with the definitions of 2 sequences $D_1,D_2,D_3,\cdots \text{and } E_1,E_2,E_3,... . $
The rest of the question says:
Use induction to prove that $E_n = D_n$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Does anyone know where to find a similar question like this?

Comment: To prove $E_n = D_n$ for all $n \geq 1$, we need to know how the sequences are defined.